# How to select postgre view (with session_user variable) in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql, session, view

### I need to use php session_user data in postgresql view. How is it possible?

I have created postgre view with session_user variable in db.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test_view AS 
SELECT T.name, TT.age
FROM test1 T INNER JOIN test2 TT ON T.client_id=TT.client_id
WHERE T.user::text=session_user::text;
```

And I have my PHP code with CodeIgnited framework. I have created session in PHP:

```
$data = array(
 'client_id' => $row->client_id,
 'user' => $row->user,
 'validated' => true
);
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

And now I try to select that view:

```
$result = $this->db->get('test_view');
```

But it is not working. The query returns 0 row.

What I'm doing wrong? 
(I know that I can make function or just select query, but I have to do this with this way - with view).

Answer (score 0):

`session_user::text` in your view definition holds the Postgres' session user (i.e. the database user you connect with), not the one in the app/php session.

Remove the where part of your definition, and add it as part of the query you run in php — using the app/php session user, of course.

Comment: Dude… It *isn't* the php session user. No ifs, no buts, no room for opinions or what you doubt or not. It just isn't. :-) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html Run `select session_user;` in psql to see for yourself… you'll be outside of PHP and it will return whatever Postgres user you used to connect to Postgres.